# Persist the dynamic data in ListView over pages in jQueryMobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquerymobile ListView in my mobile application in which the data is populating dynamically from database. I am writing the code to get data from database in the pageshow event of that page(Listview page) to populate ListView.

But the issue is when I am changing the tab, or redirecting to any other page and back to the listView page, the data is persisting only if I take data from db again. But I need a way to persist the ListView data instead of fetching it from database(if I already have the data in ListView) to improve performance.

Please let me know a good approach to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Store your data inside a localStorage. Reload and display it again when you return to that page again. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use pageload event instead of pageshow.If you use pageload then the data will be loaded only once when page is loaded.For later transition to the same page,the cached data will be displayed.
Note:This helps only if you have all the pages in single html file.

Hope this helps!

Reference:http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageload/